# How to switch between subplots of different figures inside a for loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

Consider the following code snippet,

```
%% Declare figures
figure(1); % Plot Measured (y) Vs Reference(x) data for 6 cases
figure(2); % Plot Regression fit for Measured vs Reference for 6 cases

%% Run algorithm for 6 cases
for i=1:6
:
:
subplot(3,2,i);plot(x,y); % should go to figure 1
:
linearfittype = fittype({'0','x','1'});
f = fit(f,x,y);
subplot(3,2,i);plot(f,x,y); % should go to figure 2
end
```

How do I allocate the subplots to the appropriate figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it suffices to write `figure(1)` or `figure(2)` before the `subplot` statement.

> If `h` is the handle or the Number property value of an existing figure, then `figure(h)` makes that existing figure the current figure, makes it visible, and moves it on top of all other figures on the screen. The current figure is the target for graphics output.

So:

```
%% Declare figures
figure(1); % Plot Measured (y) Vs Reference(x) data for 6 cases
figure(2); % Plot Regression fit for Measured vs Reference for 6 cases

%% Run algorithm for 6 cases
for i=1:6
:
:
figure(1) %// make figure 1 the current figure
subplot(3,2,i);plot(x,y); %// should go to figure 1
:
linearfittype = fittype({'0','x','1'});
f = fit(f,x,y);
figure(2) %// make figure 2 the current figure
subplot(3,2,i);plot(f,x,y); %// should go to figure 2
end
```